# printf and how to add dots "..." between variables and their values

Tags: bash, awk, printf

We have the following output

cat gh.log

```
 machine              status               
 =============================================================
 connection_ght 400
 pach_po 72
 timeout 311
 ping_agent 119675
 rt_machine 231
 ginco_snmp   14
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

How to print the output like this by using `printf`

```
 machine              status               
 =============================================================
 connection_ght..... 400
 pach_po............ 72
 timeout............ 311
 ping_agent......... 119675
 rt_machine......... 231
 ginco_snmp ........ 14
```

Comment: This isn't a job for the shell and `printf`. Use a proper text-processing tool (e.g. `awk`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the line of dots to the string that goes to `printf`, and have `printf` cut it to length. In shell:

```
$ for x in a bbb cccccc ; do 
    printf '%.20s %s\n' "$x.................................." blah;
  done
a................... blah
bbb................. blah
cccccc.............. blah
```

In `awk`:

```
$ printf "a 123\nbbbbbb 456\n" | 
    awk '{printf "%.20s %s\n", $1 ".....................", $2}'
a................... 123
bbbbbb.............. 456
```

In `%N.Ms`, *N* is the minimum width for the field, *M* the maximum.

---

To convert that first snippet to the second, you could do something like this:

```
$ awk 'NR <= 2 {print; next} {printf "%.20s %s\n", $1 ".....................", $2}' < gh.log
machine              status               
=============================================================
connection_ght...... 400
pach_po............. 72
etc.
```

The `NR <= 2 {print; next}` condition passes the first two lines through as-is, the rest is converted as above. Note that this assumes there are no other columns etc. Adapt to taste.

---

`printf` can take the field width as a separate parameter, if you put a `*` in its place, so we could also do this:

```
printf '%s%.*s %s\n' "$x" $(( 20 - ${#x} )) "................................" blah
```

(`${#x}` is the length of the variable `x`.) That would keep the string and the filler separated, but is perhaps a bit too unwieldy for shell or `awk`. It might be useful in C code where the memory management for string manipulations is more annoying to do.

Comment: but how to implement your code to my output example

Comment: @jango, oh sorry, I thought you meant you had a program that produces the output and wanted to modify it. It should be doable to process the text you presented with `awk`  like that, edited.